# Data exchange over 5 meter cable

Tags: arduino, communication, i2c, can, digital-communications

I have a microcontroller which needs to communicate over a cable, which will be approx. 5m long, with another very small microcontroller. The devices will be used outdoors in various conditions. The data rate will not be very high. When you connect the small uC with the cable to the big uC, a identification string and periodic (each minute) battery updates are sent from the small uC.

I thought about I2C but I'm not sure if it is designed for such needs? CAN is also possible but I think it´s a little bit overkill for my needs. Does anyone have good ideas?

EDIT:
I want to use as few pins as possible for the cable.

Comment: I'd go for RS422 or RS485 personally.

Comment: @Majenko I want to use as little as possible pins for the cables.

Comment: Half-duplex RS-485 requires a minimum of only two wires, although a common ground is recommended.

Comment: (1) I concur that I2C wasn't designed for such a use case.  It's good that you are paying attention to such things from the start.  Fewer chances that you would end up like [that guy](http://reconvolution.blogspot.com/2014/11/memoirs-of-overgrown-i2c-bus.html).  (2) Write-up about [RS-485 from the Arduino perspective](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11428).  (stylistic note) The accepted acronyms for microcontroller is uC, or MCU (microcontroler unit), or μC (fancy).  MC might stand for mega-controller.

Comment: Alternatively, since this is only a two-device network under 50 feet, good ol' RS-232 works fine and requires just three wires for full duplex (TX, RX, and Ground).

Comment: @PeterK beat me to it, but RS232 sounds like a good fit for this, 2 data pins + common ground is about as good as you can get for full-duplex without adding a *lot* of complexity to the send/rec'v electronics (single-wire full-duplex could be achieved with rf-style frequency-filtered signalling, but would seem truly wasteful here)

Comment: @PeterK Thanks very much for your answer. i will start reading on  how to test it with arduinos!

Comment: It sounds as though it is only the small uC that is doing the talking. Is there any need for communication in the other direction, at all? Or is it strictly one-way? I'm also thinking about the outside conditions you want supported and costs and availability and how well things fit with software and available peripheral hardware in the uC. Boundary conditions may abound here. Can you add more discussion about these things, including the outside conditions and how the cable will be carried and used, in practice? RS-232 and RS-485 signalling are obvious. But there are other options in mind.

Comment: If the small one is doing periodic updates, then you can just do one sided rs232. TX and Gnd only. That said, have you thought about bluetooth? 15 ft is easy.

Comment: Bluetooth would be the fewest pins possible. 0.

Comment: @jonk yes for the moment the big microcontroller just listens but maybe in the future in want to integrate bidirectional communication. The cable has to be very robust because it will be transported in bags and cars. also it will be in very rought terrain. it will be in daily use on snow and rain but also hot summer days.

Comment: So. What do you think of using coax? It's pretty robust stuff and you can even get armored stuff, if needed. You can do bidirectional transfers over a shared wire. But you already know that from I2C, I assume. Mostly, I'm thinking here about robust signalling, though. Bulletproof. (CAN is like that, but as you said it may be overkill. But cripes, you can short out CAN against the car battery and it still survives. CAN is darned good medicine when you want 'bulletproof'.)

Comment: @jonk the CAN bus may looks like a little bit overkill but it would also just require 2 pins and 3.3v right? I think i also need an transceiver for my arduino

Comment: I think CAN comes in 3.3V and 5V varieties and the 5V varieties I've seen come with a separate rail allowed so that they work fine with 3.3V uC even when using 5V signalling. For example, see the Microchip MCP25625. Also see the TI "SLLA337" paper on 3.3V CAN.

Comment: @jonk thanks very much! i will test the CAN bus and also the MAX3232.

Comment: I guess I'm really thinking about your cabling and connectors as the big issue. You may want things very easy to use and that just works all the time. I'm kind of thinking along the lines of those phantom power supply microphone XLR connectors. They have them with and without locking features and they are pretty hardy. So is some of the microphone cabling available, too. Just a thought. No idea how they'd do outside, but musicians must have to do things in bad weather. So maybe okay.

Comment: Another approach might be to use house wiring plugs and wire up special cables using outdoor extension plug wire and male connectors on both ends of it. There are fancy 30A locking connectors for that, too, and in 3 and 4 conductor varieties. Not too expensive. Available at Home Depot and Lowes. Well, that's my last thought for now.

Comment: @jonk thanks very much for your help! the xlr idea is not a bad idea. i will take a look at that but i can imagine that the connector is really big.

Comment: @perotom: big is good when you are outside with ham-handed folks helping connect things up. I like locking connectors, too, for things like these. Well, just a thought to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While CAN might be a bit "overkill", it is always to prefer if you have that option. Brief comparison or CAN versus RS232/RS422/RS485:

CAN advantages:

- Far more robust and tolerant to EMI. But in terms of the technology itself and in terms of built-in protection in a standard transceiver.
- Will work just fine without shielded cables at lower baudrates.
- Built-in error handling, CRC and frame synchronization. So there's no need to invent yet another obscure, custom UART-based protocol. Meaning CPUs don't have to waste time encoding/decoding, calculating CRC etc.
- Easy to maintain and easy to re-design from point-to-point into multi-node system, should the need arise in the future.

CAN disadvantages:

- Not really a sensible choice unless your MCU has a CAN peripheral on-chip. External CAN controllers are burdensome and a thing of the past.
- Might have slightly higher current consumption than UART-based solutions.

The cost of CAN transceivers versus RS-xxx transceivers should be about the same (except if you pick old crap transceivers like MAX232 that need 5x 1uF decoupling caps). Signal voltage levels don't matter, there's CAN and RS-xxx transceivers for both 3.3V and 5V.

The number of wires for a semi-duplex system will be 3 in either case. In the case of CAN, you have CAN H, CAN L and signal ground. In the case of for example RS-422 you have T+, T- and signal ground. Skipping signal ground is really not recommended for either case, don't listen to people telling you otherwise.

Comment: Minor point: "_... transceivers like MAX232 that need 5x 1uF decoupling caps._" The caps are for the voltage doublers to generate the (approx) +7 and -7 V from the +5 V supply. Is there a know problem with the MAX232?

Comment: @Transistor MAX202 works just as fine but only needs 100nF. Same for most second source named something-232. Jurassic technology versus Cretaceous technology... pick your favourite dinosaur.

Comment: @Lundin so i think i will take can bus. it is maybe a little bit more complicated to program but more versatile.

Comment: @perotom You might want to check if the given MCU has any pre-made drivers available. That will save you lots of work.

Comment: @Lundin i think arduino has some premade drivers. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'll also vote for RS232, you should be careful about one thing that no-one else has mentioned though. You don't say what microcontrollers you are using, but the following is true for most that I've used...

Your microcontroller will have at least one data transmit line (TX) and at least one data receive line (RX). These lines will toggle between low & high as you transmit/recieve between voltage levels of 0V & ~5V or 0V & 3.3V depending on the device. Assuming both microcontrollers use the same voltage levels then, in principle, you could just connect TX from one micro to RX of the other and vise a versa. This works for short distances & low data rates, but I think 5m is way too long for this and I also think it is bad practice to do this between systems.

Better to use a level converter (such as the MAX232 family for 0-5V systems or the MAX3232 for 0-3V systems) on each end. These convert the logic 0 to ~+12V and a logic 1 to ~-12V so that your comms line conforms to the RS232 standard electrically.

Hope this helps,

Joe

Comment: The microcontroller i currently use is a STM32F205 ARM Cortex M3. One problem more is that this device is a mobile device with only a 3.3v battery so no 12v power supply.

Comment: You don't need a 12V PSU. The devices I mentioned generate the required voltage levels internally (you'll also need 4 capacitors - values depend on the device, so look at the data sheet for those). Just be sure to use the MAX3232 version which can operate correctly with a 3.3V supply, the MAX232 operates with a 5V supply. I should add that other companies apart from Maxim make similar devices.

Comment: is going to be hard wired with connectors? e.g. RJ45    The interleaved grounds lower line impedance and improve immunity.  If there is risk of ground loops or common mode noise a ferrite toroidal with loops of flat wire or twisted pairs around it improves noise immunity. Since RS485 is much lower impedance and balanced this also improves CM noise immunity greatly. Then you can consider common CAT wire cables with plugs for convenience.

Comment: RS-232 is pretty much obsolete for any purpose nowadays. The _only_ advantage of that old junk, is that you may use it to communicate with old PCs. Apart from that, there is _never_ a reason to pick RS-232 over RS-422. Going with pure TTL level UART is not even an option outside a PCB, that's just completely unprofessional and even I2C would be a much better choice then.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the question of best alternatives (I don't really recommend it, but it can work), I have sucessfully run I2C long distances (between buildings) in production and it worked for years.

- You can reduce I2C clock rate right down to 10kHz, and put extra filter caps on the lines to filter RF out.
- Many of the chips are perfectly happy at higher currents than 1.5mA run 5,10 or 20mA depending on what your chips can handle
- Make sure you are using I2C chips (cmos schmitt thresholds) not SMBUS (ttl levels) as they are far more noise prone.
- feed the power down the same wires, have suitable bypassing.
- twisted pair/shielded cables. http://www.i2cchip.com/i2c_connector.html#Crosstalk
- use bus switch to isolate this segment from local I2C parts
- realise that errors are to be expected and design software around it. (i.e. do repeats e.g. update your display every few seconds, rather than leave it for hours between updates)
- Beware of I2C bus deadlock, which can occur from noise injecting an extra clock pulse, and make sure your master detects and deals with it. (I bet arduino stock code doesn't)

See section 19 I2C Bus Deadlock in http://www.i2cchip.com/pdfs/bl233_b.pdf